# close_old_connections in django_cron

Tags: python, django

I started django_cron

python manage.py runcrons

and then pressed cntrl+c.

Now when I try to run python manage.py runcrons, I get next message:

> python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/commands/runcrons.py:41: RemovedInDjango18Warning: close_connection is superseded by close_old_connections.
>     close_connection()

How can I unlock it?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found this fix:

```
try:
    from django.db import close_old_connections as close_connection
except ImportError:
    from django.db import close_connection
```